# Monitoring internet connection from coaxial cable into modem?

Tags: networking, internet, cable-modem, coaxial

I work at a small business and we have a business account with Optimum.  We have one of Optimum's modems, an Arris TG1672 modem.

We are having a minor problem.  Every morning it seems like, it goes out for a few minutes.  It normally comes back on its own within a few minutes, though sometimes I will immediately reset it and then it will come back as well.

This happened again this morning, I contacted Optimum support, and they said they have not seen any outages, that we have 5 days uptime.  We definitely had this issue again yesterday and a few days before.

What I am wondering is if there is any device to monitor the coaxial cable coming in from the street into our modem to see if we can detect the outage?  I don't know how frequently Optimum polls our modem to see if its connected and as mentioned, the downtime from this is small, but happens almost everyday that it's become an annoyance to everyone in my office and I am tasked with troubleshooting it.

Is there a name for a type of device that I can put between the coaxial cable coming in from the street and then go into the modem so I can monitor if we are losing service from our ISP or so I can safely say no its not our ISP and something internal is happening.  Something like

Street  ========= some device monitoring the connection ====== modem

Comment: This seems like it's skipping a few steps... Does the modem have an IP address that you can reach? *Can* you reach it when the internet is down? It'd be much easier to monitor local connectivity (the "something internal" part) than cable signal.

Comment: That's a good point and makes me glad I asked  the question.  The modem does have an external IP though it's not ever pingable and I can't go to the external IP address to see the settings, I have to do that through optimums website/web interface, which I can't do if the internet is down though I could use my phone or something to look at the status of it next time it's down.  Think that's a good next step, next time it is down, go on my hotspot and log on and see what the interface says about the modem?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: You can try pinging your modem's public ip address from your phone or from a pc receiving hotspot from your phone. If it doesn't respond, then it's down, that is providing your modem is set to reply. Sometimes they are set to not reply to external pings. So it's worth making sure the public ip responds when its all working normally first.

Comment: Do you have a separate router? Can you reach the router from inside the network? Over both IPv4 and IPv6? Is it a general IP reachability issue, or is it a DNS issue? That's the sort of thing to check to rule out internal problems.

Comment: Mine is set to not respond to external pings so even when its working like right now, I cannot ping it.

I do have a few other external IP addresses exposed that I should be able to ping normally, a web server for instance.  Perhaps next time it goes out, I should see if I can ping the webserver from my hotspot connection to see if it goes through ie the modem is passing on the request?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes the modem goes directly into a few routers.  I can reach the router from inside the network normally over IPv4.  I can test that definitely next time this goes out.

Comment: DSLReports do a connectivity test - http://www.dslreports.com/schedule - used to be free but now it looks like there's a small charge. You have to be able to accept pings, though.

Comment: A few routers, as in more than one? Actual routers with independent subnets, or just Wi-Fi APs?

Comment: @BrianKarabinchak Trying to monitor a modem in the way being asked isn't feasible - modems literally speak a different programming language than routers and require specific programs to communicate directly with them via cli. Some modems run a basic status WebUI on `192.168.100.1`, however since the TG672 is a modem+router combo, it should have a LAN accessible WebUI _(AFAIK, even modem router combos keep those two separate at the hardware level due to one not being able to communicate with the other except through the WAN interface, either a physical or CPU interface)_. _(Cont'd...)_

Comment: @BrianKarabinchak _(Cont'd...)_ If the hardware itself is remaining up, it could be a WAN DHCP issue if the modem isn't configured with a static ISP WAN IP - that'd make sense if it's happening daily, releasing/renewing the WAN IP every 24hrs. If the WAN IP changes, a few minutes to come back online would seem normal since the modem side needs to disconnect the WAN interface from the router, then disconnect the router's WAN interface to get the new WAN IP - it's not a simple up/down, which is why you normally have to power cycle both modem and router, keeping the modem unplugged for a few min

Comment: Note, nothing can replace having an ISP technician come out to check the lines. I had a very similar problem a few years ago. the call center folks couldn't see the problem at first (you have to call while the problem is occurring), but eventually found that there were periods of low signal-to-noise at the modem. tech came out, checked all the lines, and replaced 6 feet of the drop from the pole to the building to resolve the issue. no one but the ISP would have been able to help with that, and it won't impact other customers so its not an outage.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Two routers, one for our phone system, one for our computers, on different independent subnets.

Comment: I appreciate everyone talking some sense into me.  I suspect it is our router.  It happened again yesterday, and during that period I could not ping our router.  I could not access any of our apps on our local network.  Retstarting the router and not the modem was sufficient to restore access to the internet.

Now as to why the router would be having intermittent, every other day-ish issues - I need to look further into.